# Can I use a parameter for the IN clause in a MySQL query/stored proc

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe2

I want to retrieve data in Delphi using a stored procedure. I used the below SQL statement and `Initial` as a parameter:

```
SELECT * FROM "PackUser" where Initials in (:Initial)
```

It didn't select any records when the user types `A,B` in my Edit box, because it sends a single string `'A,B'` to the stored procedure. I want to add extra quotes in the middle: `'A','B'`.

How can I do this?

Comment: That won't work as you expect. You cannot parametrize value of `IN` clause. It will always be sent as a single value, so better focus on breaking that string value on DBMS side.

Comment: You can't do that, as @Victoria says. You can't parameterize values for an IN clause. You need to build it yourself using a loop, and then add it to the SQL (I usually use `Format`).

Comment: And that's not a stored procedure, BTW. It's a simple SELECT statement.

Comment: @KenWhite this is not the actual SP. But same situation. Can i do anything from sql to this?

Comment: As Victoria and I have both explained, you cannot pass the values for an IN clause via parameters. There's no alternative other than building the entire IN clause yourself, which means you can't pass it to the stored procedure. You could do it in code using SQL yourself, by either dynamically adding individual parameters for each value and building the SQL along the way. There's no clean way to use IN, and there's no way to pass the contents via a single parameter. The answer to your direct question is simple, but it won't solve your actual problem.

Comment: Which DBMS and client library do you use?

Comment: @Victoria MySQL

Comment: @Ken "there's no way to pass the contents via a single parameter" Sure you can, by writing code in the stored procedure which parses it out. Not ideal, but possible.

Comment: Is there any reason you want to do this? maybe we can suggest a different approach...

Comment: The title of your q is nothing to do with what the a actually asks.  -1

Comment: @MartynA I don't understand why you put _-1_ in your comment!!

Comment: @Sami:  Because of my down-vote.  A title which bears no relation to the contents of the q does not assist future readers.

Comment: @MartynA: I edited the title to make the context clear...

Comment: @MartynA I don't want to be rude or something, but I think you can just DV and leave  comment to explain what's wrong to the OP without the _-1_ thing, that's just my point of view.

Comment: @whosrdaddy:  Thanks.  One of the things I've never quite understood about SO is that if I now undo my -1, the OP seems to get an increase of 5 rep, which seems undeserved to me, esp. in a case like this.

Comment: @Sami:  No worries, I tend to put -1 to make it clear that my comment is intended to explain mt downvote.  Many OPs take umbrage when they get a d/v without explanation.

Comment: @MartynA I like to comment on Q/A to warn/explain to the OP,It's good when you explain what's wrong with the his post, always use comments ;-).

Comment: @MartynA: I upvoted so the net result = 0

Comment: @Jerry: Then you're creating and executing dynamic SQL in your stored procedure, which is typically a bad idea. But that wasn't the question asked, and choosing to take something out of context just to nitpick sounds like something you complain about frequently when it's done to you. Picking up bad habits? :-)

Comment: @Ken "Not ideal, but possible." And how is that not related to the question? It's a possible solution, isn't it? What are you talking about? Why are you going out of YOUR way to  nitpick?

Comment: @JerryDodge: You picked a couple of words out of an entire conversation, totally out of context, in order to quibble with them. And apparently in addition to bad habits, you've lost either your sense of humor or your reading skills - you seem to have missed the **:-)**.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like this:

```
input_string=',A,B,C.D'

SELECT * FROM "PackUser" where locate(concat(',', Initials), input_string);
```